# How to convert array of strings in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to convert string of arrays to an object.

input:

```
const test = [
  ' data1: 123',
  ' data2: 3524',
  ' data3: 5142',
  ' data4: 84521'
]
```

output:

```
{
 data1: 123,
 data2: 3524,
 data3:5142,
 data4: 84521,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and map the array to a fitting format. You can for instance do that with [`Array.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```js
const test = [
  'data1: 123',
  'data2: 3524',
  'data3: 5142',
  'data4: 84521'
];

const result = Object.fromEntries(test.map((e) => e.split(": ")))

console.log(result);
```